# Why this button is not getting center?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap V5 and i wanted to center the login button in the div and i am using *mx-auto* and also tried *text-center* but none of this is working.
Where am i getting wrong.

```
 <div className='container my-auto w-50' style={{backgroundColor:"#E8D2A6"}}>
   <div className="text-center my-4" style={{fontSize:"2.5rem"}}>Login</div>
   <div className="form-group row">
   <label htmlFor='userid' className='col-3 col-form-label' style={{fontSize:"1.3rem"}}>Enter UserId:</label>
   <div class="col-8">
   <input type="text" id="userid" className='form-control' placeholder='Enter user id'/>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div className="form-group row my-3">
   <label htmlFor='userid' className='col-3 col-form-label' style={{fontSize:"1.3rem"}}>Enter Password:</label>
   <div class="col-8">
   <input type="text" id="userid" className='form-control' placeholder='Enter Password'/>
   </div>
   </div>
   <button type='button' className="mx-auto btn btn-danger btn-block text-center">Login</button>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


 <div class='container my-auto w-50' style={{background-color:"#E8D2A6"}}>
   <div class="text-center my-4" style={{fontSize:"2.5rem"}}>Login</div>
   <div class="form-group row">
   <label htmlFor='userid' class='col-3 col-form-label' style={{fontSize:"1.3rem"}}>Enter UserId:</label>
   <div class="col-8">
   <input type="text" id="userid" class='form-control' placeholder='Enter user id'/>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row my-3">
   <label htmlFor='userid' class='col-3 col-form-label' style={{fontSize:"1.3rem"}}>Enter Password:</label>
   <div class="col-8">
   <input type="text" id="userid" class='form-control' placeholder='Enter Password'/>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
     <button type='button' class="w-auto mx-auto btn btn-danger btn-block text-center">Login</button>
   </div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this is happen so that in future i will not do the mistake

Comment: The button was taking only limited width, so applying margin won't help. The row class takes the full width and hence the button can take the full width too. Then by using w-auto, I decreased the width of the button.